# Find quotient and remainder using long division $(x^6+x^4+x^2+1)÷(x^2+1)$

Tags: polynomials

Find quotient and remainder using long division 
$$(x^6+x^4+x^2+1)÷(x^2+1).$$

I tried replacing with $0$ until I ended with $0x^2+x+1$ as a quotient...

Answer (score 2):

$$x^6+x^4+x^2+1=x^4(x^2+1)+x^2+1=(x^2+1)(x^4+1),$$
which gives that the quotient is $x^4+1$ and the remainder is $0$.

Comment: It should be long division

Comment: @Nawar Ashraf It's the same, but I don't know to draw it.

Comment: @NawarAshraf right, he factored the dividend and the divisor showed up. Divide the rightmost expression by $x^2+1$ and you'll see ...

Answer (score 2):

Alternative hint:  let $y=x^2$ then the dividend is:

$$\require{cancel}
y^3+y^2+y+1 = \frac{y^4-1}{y-1}=\frac{(y^2-1)(y^2+1)}{y-1}=\frac{\cancel{(y-1)}(y+1)(y^2+1)}{\cancel{y-1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x^2+1\quad|\quad & +x^6+x^4+x^2+1 \quad| \quad x^4+1\\
&+x^6 + x^4\\
&(-)\quad(-)\\
&\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\\
& \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad +x^2+1\\
& \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad +x^2+1\\
& \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad (-)\quad(-)\\
& \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\\\\
&\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad0\\
& \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\\\\
\end{align}